# LINQ Query from one collection to populate the other one

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list **GroupMembershipValidList** that contains objects of type GroupMembershipUploadInput.

This GroupMembershipUploadInput class definition looks like

```
   public class GroupMembershipUploadInput
    {
        public string chpt_cd { get; set; }}
        public string cnst_last_nm { get; set; }
        public string appl_src_cd { get; set; }

    }
```

I have simplified the definition for the sake of simplicity.

Now I have another list **_validChapterCodes** (`public List<ChapterCodeValidationOutput> _validChapterCodes { get; set; }`)

that contains objects of type

```
public class ChapterCodeValidationOutput
{
    public string chpt_cd { get; set; }
    public string appl_src_cd { get; set; }
}
```

So, What I want to do is .. if the chpt_cd from list A matches list B , then populate the appl_src_cd names from list B to list A objects.

How would I do it in LINQ ?

I tried ...

```
gmvo.GroupMembershipValidList.GroupMembershipUploadInputList.Where(x => gmvo._validChapterCodes.Contains(x.chpt_cd)).Select(y => y.appl_src_cd);
```

But I know I am not doing it properly .

Comment: You should really look at giving your properties meaningful names.  It's a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ has a *functional* approach, meaning it's for getting values out of a set of existing values, not for *manipulating* existing values.

So you can't avoid at least one `foreach` here. I'd do it like this:

```
foreach(var chapter in _validChapterCodes)
{
    ChapterCodeValidationOutput output = GroupMembershipValidList.FirstOrDefault(e =>
        e.chpt_cd == chapter.chpt_cd);
    if (input != null) chapter.appl_src_cd = input.appl_src_cd;
}
```

`FirstOrDefault()` returns the first element from your input list with a matching `chpt_cd` or `null` if there is no matching element.

---

EDIT: From your question I'm not sure if you wanted it that way or the other way around (what is *list A* and *list B*?). So for completeness the other way:

```
foreach(var input in GroupMembershipValidList)
{
    var chapter = _validChapterCodes.FirstOrDefault(e =>
        e.chpt_cd == input.chpt_cd);
    if (chapter != null) input.appl_src_cd = chapter.appl_src_cd;
}
```

Comment: Okay ,but if for the second object in the list the chpt_cd is the same as the first object , for the second object appl_src_cd is coming as null. How can I avoid it ?

Comment: No, if it's the same `chpt_cd` it would return the same element. You did not specify in your question if those `chpt_cd`s are unique or what you want to populate `appl_src_cd` with if they are not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a LINQ expression.

```
var a = new List<GroupMembershipUploadInput>
{
    new GroupMembershipUploadInput() {chpt_cd = "A" },
    new GroupMembershipUploadInput() {chpt_cd = "A2"" },
    new GroupMembershipUploadInput() {chpt_cd = "A3" }
};

var b = new List<ChapterCodeValidationOutput>
{
    new ChapterCodeValidationOutput() {chpt_cd = "A", appl_src_cd = "ACode"},
    new ChapterCodeValidationOutput() {chpt_cd = "C2", appl_src_cd = "C22"},
    new ChapterCodeValidationOutput() {chpt_cd = "A3", appl_src_cd = "A33"}
};


var result = a.Select(s => new GroupMembershipUploadInput
{
    chpt_cd = s.chpt_cd,
    appl_src_cd = b.Any(u => u.chpt_cd == s.chpt_cd) ?
                          b.First(v => v.chpt_cd == s.chpt_cd).appl_src_cd:string.Empty
}).ToList();
```

Assuming a is a collection of `GroupMembershipUploadInput` and b is a collection of `ChapterCodeValidationOutput`

Comment: Will it populate the same collection a here ?

Comment: Yes. result will be all a new list with all the items from a, but with appl_src_cd property filled with values from collection b for the matching items.

Comment: That's the point, this creates a _new_ list, but does not populate the _existing_ list like the question asked for.

Comment: You can do a `foreach` on existing collection and update the property of each item after checking it in the second collection 
(Shown in the other answer). Unless i am super obese with a new list allocation, I prefer the single LINQ statement over the foreach. Let GC take care of rest.